# Comparing two lists of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

my first list of set:

```
set1 = [
    {'read', 'execute', 'helloworld.exe'}, 
     {'read', 'pinglog', 'write'}, 
     {'read', 'nya'}, 
     {'read', 'execute', 'write', 'goodluck'}
]
```

now I am looking if these different sets below are in the first list of sets.

```
final = [
    {'read', 'nya'}, 
    {'helloworld.exe', 'write'},
    {'execute', 'nya'}, 
    {'read', 'pinglog'}, 
    {'write', 'pinglog'}
]
```

the expected outcome is

```
OK
Access denied
Access denied
OK
OK
OK
```

This is my code, I know not much, but my head is already aching for I am trying to do this for two days:

```
for j in range(len(final)):
    for i in range(len(set1)):
        if final[j] == set1[i]:
            print("OK")

    print("Access denied")
```

Comment: it should print OK if the a combination in "final" is in the "set1".

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be testing if your sets are a *subset*; you can do so with the [`<=` operator on the sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
>>> final[0], set1[2]  # same
({'nya', 'read'}, {'nya', 'read'})
>>> final[0] <= set1[2]
True
>>> final[3], set1[1]  # subset
({'pinglog', 'read'}, {'write', 'pinglog', 'read'})
>>> final[3] <= set1[1]
True
>>> final[4], set1[1]  # subset
({'write', 'pinglog'}, {'write', 'pinglog', 'read'})
>>> final[4] <= set1[1]
True
```

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to test a given set against all sets in `set1`:

```
for request in final:    
    if any(request <= s for s in set1):
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Access denied")
```

Demo:

```
>>> for request in final:
...     if any(request <= s for s in set1):
...         print("OK")
...     else:
...         print("Access denied")
...
OK
Access denied
Access denied
OK
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a generator expression to check if any x is  subset of any set in set1, if so we print `OK` else `Access Denied`

```
for i in ('OK' if any(x <= y for y in set1) else 'Access Denied' for x in final):
    print(i)
```

> ```
> OK
> Access Denied
> Access Denied
> OK
> OK
> ```